# Z Schema and page limits

Tags: textcomp

I have a document with a Z Schema which is longer than a page and some often predicates are also quite long. I find that my compiled document loses the lower area of the schema at the end of the page. Also the lines with long predicates don't roll around the page and just disappear of the edge of the page. Any advise would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,mathbbol} 
\usepackage{color,graphics,graphicx,epsfig} 
\usepackage{rotating,subfig} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} 
\captionsetup{font={small,it},labelfont=small} 
\usepackage{hyperref} \usepackage{zed-csp} 
\def\fuzz{{\large\itshape f\kern0.1em}{\normalsize\textit{} fuzz}} 
\let\Fuzz=\fuzz
     \def\ZRM{{\rm ZRM}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{schema}{\Delta FlightsDatabase}
  FlightsDatabase\\
  FlightsDatabase'\\
  CityA?, CityB? : AIRPORTCITY\\
  CityAAC,CityBAC : AIRPORTCODE\\
 \where \forall x, y, z : Company,CityAAC,CityBAC | 
    \ran AirportSet \in {AirportName, CityA? } @ y = CityAAC \Land \ran AirportSet \in {AirportName, CityB? } @ y = CityBAC \implies {CityAAC,CityBAC} \in \ran FlightAPSet @ \dom FlightAPSet \dres FlightCompSet | x = \ran FlightCompSet\\ 
    FlightsDatabase = FlightsDatabase' 
    \end{schema}{} 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: if the markup you have used isn't allowing line and page breaking there is probably some different markup you can use but hard to say given no information, please show a complete small document that demonstrates the problem,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle\\

Comment: @DavidCarlisle\\


\begin{document}

Predicates

\where

\forall x, y, z : Company,CityAAC,CityBAC  | \ran AirportSet \in {AirportName, CityA? } @ y = CityAAC \Land \ran AirportSet \in {AirportName, CityB? } @ y = CityBAC \implies {CityAAC,CityBAC} \in \ran FlightAPSet @ \dom FlightAPSet \dres FlightCompSet | x = \ran FlightCompSet\\

 FlightsDatabase = FlightsDatabase'

\end{schema}{}

\end{document}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The header of the document is:
{\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,mathbbol}
\usepackage{color,graphics,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{rotating,subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\captionsetup{font={small,it},labelfont=small}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{zed-csp}
\def\fuzz{{\large\itshape f\kern0.1em}{\normalsize\textit{} fuzz}}
\let\Fuzz=\fuzz
\def\ZRM{{\rm ZRM}}}

Comment: You can edit the question and use the `{}` for code sections I'll do it this time)

Comment: I tried to reconstruct a document from your comments but (a) it's not a very minimal document (do you really need all those packages to show the problem? and (b) it generates `! Misplaced \crcr.
\@zskip #1->\crcr ` should there be a begin{schema} somewhere?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Thanks for trying David, I edited the Schema.  Note that the original document has another longer schema.  Package setup is a wild guess.